# How do I fix a broken OS X update that shows as both Available and Installed?

Tags: macos, xcode, software-update

The "Command Line Tools (OS X 10.10) for Xcode 7.0" is not working correctly.  It installs and shows in the "Updates Installed" section, however it is still listed in the "Updates Available" section.  Oddly, it's being shown in the "Updates Installed" sections multiple times -- once for each time I tried to install it.

I have restarted and it persists.  How can I fix this?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for the standard toolkit first...

- In Disk Utility, "Verify Disk Permissions" and if necessary "Fix Disk Permissions".  Also "Verify Disk" and if necessary "Repair Disk".
- Reset Home folder permissions & ACLs using [OnyX](http://www.titanium.free.fr/onyx.html)  - Maintenance tab/permissions, tick the box at the top then Execute.
- Update to 10.10.5 [or re-apply if already updated] using the [10.10.5 combo update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1832), not the delta from App Store

Comment: I repaired permissions and installed the update again and it finally went away from the Available list.  Now, it's listed 5 times in "Installed Updates" oh well.  Did not use OnyX or combo update.

Comment: The 'toolkit' is really to do all 3 ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin, could you add some detail to your answer about how to "update permissions"?  A link would be fine.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I took the liberty of adding a little detail to your answer.  I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

I had the [same problem](https://discussions.apple.com/message/28920110#28920110).  What ultimately worked for me was switching to a different WiFi network.  Not sure *why* that worked but if you're still stuck, it's worth a try.